# IIS Web Deploy Using RM task missing in Pipeline

Tags: iis, tfs, webdeploy

I have installed the task successfully on TFS Server 2015.[Shows task successfully installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTnBI.jpg)

After installing the task when i try to build or release the solution i am not able to see the task in pipeline. [Task_missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiYwm.png)

I have read the notes and it shows that extension is compatible with the given TFS Version.
I am running ASP.NET code and trying to deploy on Azure VM with this extension.
Am i missing something here? Please Advise.

Comment: I am running TFS Server 2015 update 3

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/379384/cant-see-tasks-in-iis-web-app-deployment-using-win.html

Comment: Have you used to be able to see this task before?

Comment: No after installing the extension, it shows installed but not visible

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking for the task in Deploy session. Also try to search it from All.

We have met similar issue before, could not able to see some task in release pipeline.

The workaround is uninstalling one of any installed build related extension.

You could also give a try with this workaround check whether this do the trick.

Comment: Yes I have tried in looking under All section. I have tried uninstalling and installing the extension. Under my organization, admin who installed the extension he is not able to see in his system.

Comment: Hi @YoginBhatt Thanks for your kindly response. That's the same situation we used to have. The solution is uninstalling an other build related extension in Extensions list, not the one you could not see. After this sign out the web portal and sign in again, check if you are able to see IIS Web Deploy Using RM task . This should do the trick.

Comment: No i have new task assigned from my organization. So i didn't get a chance to follow up on it. I appreciate you helping to resolve this issue.

Comment: @YoginBhatt OK, thanks for getting back. If you have time working on it, any update feel free to share here.